# Regex condition: letters except 'crfl' at the end of the word or string are deleted?

Tags: python, regex

I tried:

```
re.sub(r'[^crfl](?=(\.|\,|\s|\Z))', '', val, flags=re.I)
```

on string

```
car. cupid, fof bob lol. koc coc, cob
```

but the result is:

```
car cupi fof bo lol koc coc co
```

I don't uderstand, why lookahead assertion deleted commas and dots.

The result I'm for is:

```
car. cupi, fof bo lol. koc coc, co
```

Comment: `[^crfl]` matches `.`, `,`, all that is not `c`, `r`, `f`, `l`. Are you only dealing with ASCII letters? BTW, `\Z` is not supported by Python `re`.

Comment: I understand now. No, I'm working with Unicode, French language.

Comment: Unfortunately, `re` does not work with Unicode that well. Can you use PyPi `regex` module?

Comment: Oh, I see that Python `re` does not support `\z`, but supports `\Z` :)

Comment: Thanks, I will look on PyPi regex.

Comment: I think vks `\w(?<![crfl0-9_])\b` should work for you with `re`. Use it with the `re.U` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^crfl.,](?=(\.|\,|\s|\Z))
```

just include `.,` in `negation list`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yX8zV8/5

or simply

```
\w(?<![crlf])\b
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/1

Comment: Using this approach the list should be expanded with a lot more characters. French letters regex is `[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]`. So, the answer is `(?![crfl])[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]\b` but `\b` should be Unicode aware (`re.U` is required).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/1 this should do it for him with `u` flag

Comment: But `\w` matches digits and an underscore.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Easy fix...just add to character class in lookbehind

Comment: I think [OP's other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155327/how-to-replace-every-character-with-regex-as-opposite-to-str-replace) should be reopened. Please click Reopen if you agree.